# Add attribute in magento order email confirmation

Tags: sales-order, email-templates, order-email

Need some help to add a `custom attribute to my email order confirmation`. I have an attribute Location that I would like to be shown under the product sku in the order confirmation email.

Could any supply me with the code for displaying the location attribute under the sku?

Have tried a lot but no success yet.

I use `magento 1 1.9.2`

Comment: Something like that `$locationValue = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product)->getData("location");` not work for you ?

Comment: Where to I add the code in the order default.phtml?

Comment: In your code, where is display the product sku ? Add my code just after.

Comment: HI Not good add this. Could you please show me the code and where to insert it?

Comment: in the default.phtml